# finding and copying multiple files into one folder based on the newest file

Tags: python, file, copy, file-move

I have to do some analytics of multiple files which lay in different folder paths.

Also i just have a List of the file names (but not the complete filenames) and have to search for them in multiple paths and dont know what folder path is the correct for which file.

What i have as filename (example): "20222023"
What the file name actually is: "XX_20222023_x3_20230101_0000_b1.xml"

Since the filenames that i have can be in one of three paths i would like to just put them all in a list and copy them all together in a target folder.

One extra problem: In the origin folder of the file can be multiple files with the same filename that i got. They just differ in date and time of creation.

So for example. In one folder would be:
"XX_20222023_x3_20230101_0000_b1.xml" and
"XX_20222023_x3_20230102_0000_b1.xml"

and i just want to copy the newest file.

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Search for ctime and mtime.